# Getting data of everyday's same time period

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have a table containing a month's transaction data with `transaction_time` stored in a `DATETIME` field.

I want to get all the transactions that occurred between `12:00:00` and `13:00:00`, irrespective of the day.  `WHERE transaction_time BETWEEN x AND y` would have to be date-specific, but I need that same time period of all dates.

How can I filter for such a range in a MySQL query?

Comment: You should edit the question with sample data, desired results, and your own attempt to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter on the result of applying MySQL's [`HOUR()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour) function to your `DATETIME` value:

```
WHERE HOUR(transaction_time) = 12
```

If you need to filter across more exact time ranges, you could convert the times to seconds as follows:

```
WHERE TIME_TO_SEC(TIME(transaction_time)) BETWEEN TIME_TO_SEC('12:00:00')
                                              AND TIME_TO_SEC('13:00:00')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
select * from transactions
where convert(time, transaction_time) between '12:00:00' and '13:00:00'
```

for MSSQL and:

```
select * from transactions
where extract(hour_second from transaction_time) between 120000 and 130000
```

for MySql.

Comment: These would cover `12:00:00` through to `13:59:59`.

Answer (score 0):

You have two time constraints. The first is to restrict the dates to a particular month. Assume we get the first day of the month as a date parameter:

```
where   transaction_time >= :searchMonth 
    and transaction_time < Date_Add( :searchMonth, interval 1 month )
```

Now we're only looking at rows from that month. Now limit it to the hour specified. Assume we get the hour as an integer parameter:

```
    and extract( hour from transaction_time ) between :hr and (:hr + 1)
```

Now that final part is based on your own code. Let me say that when the requirements read "during a particular hour of the day" and the request reads "during the noon hour" then I am wont to write it like this:

```
    and extract( hour from transaction_time ) >= :hr 
    and extract( hour from transaction_time ) < (:hr + 1)
```

because hour 13 (1PM) is the first click of the next hour. So if there is a transaction time at exactly 13:00:00 and you use `between`, then it will show up when looking at the noon hour and also when looking at the 1PM hour. That is NOT generally a desired result. You may want to verify that with your analyst.

So the complete filter, the way I would write it, is this:

```
where   transaction_time >= :searchMonth 
    and transaction_time < Date_Add( :searchMonth, interval 1 month )
    and extract( hour from transaction_time ) >= :hr 
    and extract( hour from transaction_time ) < (:hr + 1)
```